# Visual Studio cannot start debugging for C++ project 0x80070057

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Randomly (and infrequently), Visual Studio (2017) will abruptly refuse to run my C++ project. This will suddenly start happening in the middle of a session.

Visual Studio will still build the project and generate the executable, however, the following cryptic error message appears every time I want to run my program. No changes were made to the configuration or project and it strangely happens after an innocent build.

[image: visual studio error message]

(*It goes without saying but I tried extensively checking for solutions to this problem and no solution worked or was applicable*)

Whether I add a new configuration setting or play with the existing settings (Release/Debug, x86/x64), nothing fixes it **except performing a full repair** (and that takes a very long time). Creating a new project didn't help either,  but running it in VS 2015 is successful.

This happens approximately once a week, so I would greatly appreciate knowing how this error can be fixed (or at least avoided).

Comment: It could be coming from a plugin/extension.  Try disabling some or all of the ones you use, particularly ones installed or updated shortly before you frst noticed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more experience with it, it appears just to be an issue with Visual Studio when builds are too large and executed too often (it happened to multiple computers). More specifically, it could come about as a result of using many templates and applying a large number of explicit template specializations. By building with only the template specializations I need for testing, the issue doesn't come up.

Comment: Thank you for revisiting an old question with the answer you found!

Comment: The correlation is a weak one, the debugger doesn't care about templates at all and they completely disappear in the final code.  Possibly more relevant is the size of the final executable file.  The standard scourge on Windows machines is lame anti-malware, getting its underwear in a bundle from an executable file appearing from seemingly no-where.  Few commercial products are up to the task on a dev machine, favor the one included with the OS.

Comment: What seemed strange is that **nothing** except repairing the entire installation will allow me to build my code again. I mentioned templates because they were the reason the code bloated so much. Visual Studio and Microsoft products in general aren't the most reliable.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by VS mixing release and debug binaries for me. I have a script which cleans all the output directories, including the garbage VS puts into the projects .vs and Windows Temp folder. This always fixes the issue for me.